# Automated way to purge SPO User Profiles

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

As part of a clean up task, I'm looking for **a way to programmatically purge deleted AAD accounts from the User Profile Manager in Sharepoint Online.**

I was using the Sharepoint Powershell module (Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell) to manually do it, using the `Remove-SPOUserProfile` commandlet, which worked perfectly if I was using it in an interactive session. But as soon as I tried implementing my script into Azure Automation I found that particular module falls back to Basic Authentication when using a PSCredential object in the `Connect-SPOService` statement. And Basic Auth is blocked at my Organisation (I can't see them allowing it just for me!)

I found the PnP Module (PnP.PowerShell), which does allow authentication via stored credentials. But it doesn't have an equivalent User Profile Remove cmdlet.

Finally, I tried resorting to pure REST API, and while I can get an existing user profile, I can't get a profile for an account that has been deleted (marked as 'Profiles Missing from Import' in the SPO ProfMngr.aspx page). This is because the `SP.UserProfiles.PeopleManager/GetPropertiesFor(accountName=@v)` API needs to have an exact match (eg `i:0#.f|membership|vardhaman@siteurl.onmicrosoft.com`), and when an AAD account is deleted the profile username gets `DELETED-<GUID>` appended to it.

So my questions are:

1. Am I right or wrong about the sharepoint module and stored creds? (IE, so the module can be used from Azure Automation with a service principal or service account)
2. Am I right or wrong about the PnP module and it is missing the similar `Remove-SPOUserProfile`?
3. With the REST API, how do you search for profiles, especially profiles "missing from import"?
4. Is there some way to predict what the `DELETED-<GUID>` will be for a given user? Because I was able to get a user profile if I looked up the full deleted name and supply that to my REST call.

The official documentation on this is light - the old traditional sharepoint APIs aren't being developed any more, in favour of MS Graph, but the Graph Documentation doesn't seem to cover my particular use case.

Any pointers appreciated

**Update 1**

Thanks @Michael Han_MSFT.

I was using a pre-release/nightly build (0.3.32) but looking at Release documentation so didn't realise remove profile was in there.

I'm still getting problems though:

```
Connect-PnPOnline `
-url "https://<tenantname>.sharepoint.com" `
-ClientId $ClientId `
-ClientSecret $ClientSecret

# $guest1 = Guest account's email address

$azureEmail = ($guest1 -replace "@", "_") + "#ext#@<tenantname>.onmicrosoft.com"

Remove-PnPUserProfile `
-LoginName $azureEmail


Remove-PnPUserProfile : The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
At line:11 char:1
+ Remove-PnPUserProfile `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Remove-PnPUserProfile], WebException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Net.WebException,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.UserProfiles.RemoveUserProf
   ile
```

So I tweaked the URL:

```
Connect-PnPOnline `
-url "https://<tenantname>-admin.sharepoint.com" `
-ClientId $ClientId `
-ClientSecret $ClientSecret

$azureEmail = ($guest1 -replace "@", "_") + "#ext#@azurediagovt.onmicrosoft.com"

Remove-PnPUserProfile `
-LoginName $azureEmail

Remove-PnPUserProfile : 
At line:11 char:1
+ Remove-PnPUserProfile `
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Remove-PnPUserProfile], HttpRequestException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.UserProfiles.RemoveUserProfile
```

So you can see if I go to `<tenantname>` I get a 401, but if I go to `<tenantname>-name` the response is simply blank.

I was certain I had given my App the right permissions (*Is there some way to review what permissions have been assigned?*)

In AppInv.aspx I think had this permissions code (I was following a couple of blogs):

```
<AppPermissionRequests AllowAppOnlyPolicy="true">
 <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/content/Tenant" Right="FullControl"/>
 <AppPermissionRequest Scope="http://sharepoint/social/Tenant" Right="FullControl"/>
</AppPermissionRequests>
```

As a further test, I tried the PnP version of what I was doing in REST (`Get-PnpUserProfileProperty`) and got

```
Get-PnPUserProfileProperty : Current user is not a tenant administrator.
At line:1 char:1
+ Get-PnPUserProfileProperty -Connection $pnpctx -Account "scottdu@data ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPUserProfileProperty], ServerException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.UserProfiles.GetUserProfileProperty
```

Which is strange, because REST would give me a `results.d` response.

At this stage, I could look at making the App Id a Sharepoint Service Admin (I already have approval to allow Azure Automation to have whatever rights it needs to solve this).

(**Update 1a:** Made no difference, unless there is a delay between assigning the role and the permissions taking affect).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AAD registered app can be used to connect PnpOnline and delete user profile. Please see my below steps:
(Main refer article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread)

**Step1:Registering an Azure AD application in the Azure Active Directory tenant that is linked to your Office 365 tenant and grant permission**

1. Use admin account to access https://portal.azure.com/#blade/Microsoft_AAD_RegisteredApps. Click “New registration” and create a name of your app.
2. Go to “API permissions” and click on the "Add a permission" button and  grant SharePoint API permission.
3. Select needed permissions．
4. Admin need to consent for those permissions, after that in status column will show green.

**Step2: Create a self signed certificate and connect with app**

1. Go to this link（https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/solution-guidance/security-apponly-azuread#setting-up-an-azure-ad-app-for-app-only-access）, copy the scripts and save as “Create-SelfSignedCertificate.ps1”.
2. Run below command with PowerShell. You will be asked to give a password to encrypt your private key, and both the .PFX file and .CER file will be exported to the current folder.

> .\Create-SelfSignedCertificate.ps1 -CommonName "YourCompanyName"
> -StartDate 2020-1-09 -EndDate 2022-10-01

3. Go to AAD app,　ｃlick on "Certificates & secrets" in the left menu bar. Click on the "Upload certificate" button, select the .CER file you generated and upload it.

**Step3: Connect pnp online and perform delete profile**

> $ Connect-PnPOnline -ClientId <$application client id as copied over
> from the AAD app registration above> -CertificatePath '<$path to the
> PFX file generated by the PowerShell script above>'
> -CertificatePassword (ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText "<$password assigned to the generated certificate pair above>" -Force) -Url
> https://<$yourtenant>.sharepoint.com -Tenant
> "<$tenantname>.onmicrosoft.com"
> ＄Remove-PnPUserProfile -LoginName $UPN

For REST api way, I found this article noted REST for delete user profile is not implemented.
(https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/work-with-user-profiles-in-sharepoint)

Comment: That's it! Using cert authentication was the answer. That isn't something I usually do, so I was trying "normal" clientid/clientsecret style authentication. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could try the command : `Remove-PnPUserProfile`

https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Remove-PnPUserProfile.html

You should install the prerelease version of PnP.PowerShell:
https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PnP.PowerShell/0.3.8-nightly

Update:

You could try to use tenant administrator account to connect the sharepoint admin site, then run the command  `Remove-PnPUserProfile`. This works for me:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @michael han_msft - updated my original post with the results of your suggestion

Comment: Michael: I get a bit confused between when to use `<tenantname>.sharepoint.com` vs `<tenantname>-admin.sharepoint.com` . My understanding is `-admin` is for tenant-wide, and user profiles are tenant-wide....

Comment: Please try to use administrator account to connect sharepoint admin site. Check if it works for you

Comment: You are right. You need to connect to the tenant admin website <tenantname>-admin.sharepoint.com to use the command.